# How to calculate the amount of weeks between two week pickers

Tags: javascript, html, calculation, week-number

I created two week pickers (html input type="week"). I want to know how much weeks are in between the two weeks selected. These are my two html week pickers:

```html
<input type="week" id="weekPicker1" required="required" min="1971-W01" max="2071-W52" value="2021-W01">
<input type="week" id="weekPicker2" required="required" min="1971-W01" max="2071-W52" value="2021-W52">
```

It returns `2021-W01` and `2021-W52` as a string.

In this case there are 52 weeks between the dates. But how can I make Javascript know this as well?

I have this Javascript code to make sure I get the years and weeks as numbers:

```js
// Get dates in usable format.
let startDate = inputFields[0].value.split("-");
let startYear = Number(startDate[0]); //2021
let startWeek = Number(startDate[1].replace("W", "")); //1

let endDate = inputFields[1].value.split("-");
let endYear = Number(endDate[0]); //2021
let endWeek = Number(endDate[1].replace("W", "")); //52
```

But now, how do I calculate this?

**I thought of this:**

```js
var yearDiff = endYear - startYear;
var amountOfWeeks = endWeek - startWeek;

amountOfWeeks += yearDiff * 52;
```

I think it nearly works, except not every year has 52 weeks (leap year). So how should I do this efficiently?

**Edit:**

I would like to see it in pure JS. No library or things like that. And I want the amount of weeks based on a calendar like [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021). So calculation based on a 7 day week will not give what I want.

In the end I need to use the weeks to do calculations. So using a date picker to select weeks still seems wrong. I also tested if I could do the calculation based on days etc, but it will give wrong results. Calculation I have to do: (selected length of weeks) : (max amount of weeks in year) * 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 52 weeks + 1 day in a year and 52 weeks + 2 days in a leap year. So your suggestion `amountOfWeeks += yearDiff * 52;` does not seem accurate. The below function converts the start and end year and weeks into miliseconds, subract and convert back into weeks. It should work with leap years. I haven't tested it though.

```js
function compareWeeks(startYear, startWeek, endYear, endWeek) {
    
    const start =
        new Date(startYear, 0).getTime() + startWeek * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    const end = 
        new Date(endYear, 0).getTime() + endWeek * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    const diff = Math.abs(end - start)
    const diffWeeks = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7
    return diffWeeks
}
```

**Update for ISO-week-numbering year (your use case):**
According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year), an ISO Year has either 52 or 53(ISO Leap Year) weeks. **53** when it starts or ends with Thirsday else **52**. Checkout the below code:

```js
function weeksInBetween(startYear, startWeek, endYear, endWeek) {
    let diff = 0
    for (let i = startYear; i < endYear; i++) {
        const has53Weeks = isISOLeapYear(i)
        if (has53Weeks) {
            diff += 53
        } else {
            diff += 52
        }
    }

    return (diff += endWeek - --startWeek)
    /* 
        the '--startWeek' makes sure the starting week
        is not subtracted from the result, because you
        want the result to be inclusive'
        
    */
}

function isISOLeapYear(year) {
    const startsWithThursday =
        new Date(year, 0, 1).toString().split(' ')[0] === 'Thu'
    const endsWithThursday =
        new Date(year, 11, 31).toString().split(' ')[0] === 'Thu'

    if (startsWithThursday || endsWithThursday) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

console.log(
    weeksInBetween(2020, 1, 2021, 52), // 105
    weeksInBetween(2009, 1, 2010, 52), // 105
    weeksInBetween(2021, 1, 2021, 52), // 52
    weeksInBetween(2021, 1, 2022, 52), // 104
    weeksInBetween(2021, 1, 2021, 1)   // 1
)
```

Comment: Does startWeek need to be 0 if week number 1 is selected? Because if I do `compareWeeks(2021, 0, 2021, 52)` I get 52 weeks. If I change 0 to 1, I get 51. Also, if I do `compareWeeks(2020, 0, 2021, 52)` I get `104.28571428571429` as result. Which I think should be 105. Since 2020 has 53 weeks and 2021 52. 53 + 52 = 105.

Comment: startWeek should start with 1. because the difference between 1 and 52 is 51. but if you want it to return 52 then you can do something like ` return diffWeeks + 1`.

Comment: the difference between 2020-W01 and 2021-W52 should be `104.28571428571429` not 105.
there are 52 weeks + 2 days (366) not 53(371) weeks in 2020. I am not sure why input `type="week"` allows 53 weeks

Comment: look at this: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021. That is basicly the way I want to see it. And there week 53 is used in 2020. Its about the week numbers.

Comment: And what should I use instead of a week picker? Select fields? I would still have 53 weeks in a year...

Comment: @Allart I have updated the answer for ISO Week Numbers, i think it solves your problem now,   
Instead of week fields i recommend using `select`s , with 53 weeks only for those years that start or end with Thursday, you can use the above helper function for that.

Comment: Wauw, tnx alot! This is indeed working exactly as I was hoping for. Super glad you wanted to help me out. I will now figure out how it works :)

Comment: @Allart thanks man, I didn't knew about "ISO date format"  before. I now know that.
Just make sure that your end date is not smaller than start date, results may be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date-fns` and [`differenceInCalendarWeeks`](https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/differenceInCalendarWeeks).

```js
const result = differenceInCalendarWeeks(
  startDate,
  endDate
)
```

Comment: Hmm, im not a big fan of library's etc. I would like to see a native JS solution. Still thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if you don't want the import, you can [check the source of the library](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/differenceInCalendarWeeks/index.ts) for a solution. In this case, it does what [@userharris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16232210/userharis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69255769/14956277) says: get the millisecond start of each week and convert their difference back into weeks.

Comment: Doing date calculations in native JS is a solved problem. Why try to resolve it other than for educational purposes?